# Converting dtype: period[M] to string format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have converted my dates in to an Dtype M format as I don't want anything to do with the dates. Unfortunately I cannot plot with this format so I want now convert this in to strings.

So I need to group my data so I can print out some graphs by months.
But I keep getting a serial JSON error when my data is in `dtype:Mperiod`
so I want to convert it to strings.

```
df['Date_Modified'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Collection_End_Date']).dt.to_period('M')  
#Add a new column called Date Modified to show just month and year

df = df.groupby(["Date_Modified", "Entity"]).sum().reset_index()
#Group the data frame by the new column and then Company and sum the values

df["Date_Modified"].index = df["Date_Modified"].index.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

It returns a string of numbers, but I need it to return a string output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for set `Series` to strings in last step:

```
df["Date_Modified"]= df["Date_Modified"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

Or set it before `groupby`, then converting to month period is not necessary:

```
df['Date_Modified'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Collection_End_Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df = df.groupby(["Date_Modified", "Entity"]).sum().reset_index()
```